# Validator is only invoked when the input value is specified

Tags: validation, jsf, error-handling

I have this a field:

```
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{user.user.email}" 
             title="Email" validator="#{user.user.validateEmail}" />
```

The `validateEmail` method checks if the email address's length is greater than 0, if not, it throws an `Exception`. I thought this would work, but the method is called only if you enter a value. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validator is not called if the field is empty.  If you need a value, set the required attribute to true for the control.

Comment: But so i can't change the default error message, unless i use Bundles / Custom validator class, right?

Comment: Yes, you will need a custom message bundle.  You won't need a custom validator in order to override the required message.  If you provide a custom bundle in your faces-config.xml, then in that bundle you can set the appropriate properties ( i.e. javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED ) property to your message.  I believe this may be a 1.2 feature though.